# JMeter - how to convert a human readable date time into Unix timestamp

Tags: datetime, jmeter, timestamp, performance-testing, unix-timestamp

How can human readable date time format(yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss ) be converted into Unix timestamp?

For example I have following date  2019.07.12 08:00:00 that need to be converted into unix time format?

Is there a way to do this in JMeter?

Comment: There's a thread that asks for something similar, but the conversion is the other way round, from timestamp to date. Nevertheless you may find it helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461759/jmeter-converting-extracted-time-stamp-value-to-date-format

Comment: Do you want to assume the time in in the local timezone or UTC?  Assume daylight savings time is in effect for the current time?

Comment: Time is in UTC , and I need to convert it into Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Flow Control Action and add in it a JSR223PreProcessor with this code

```
 def date = Date.parse("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss", yourDate)
vars.put("date", date.getTime().toString())
```

You can then use:

> ${date}

If using JMeter 5.3, add groovy-dateutil to lib folder of JMeter, due to this regression :

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64647

Comment: Hi, I tried this but unfortunately, I'm getting the following exception:                              
 2020-08-20 17:16:55,084 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.util.Date.parse() is applicable for argument types: (String, String) values: [yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss, 2020.08.21 08:00:00]
Possible solutions: parse(java.lang.String), wait(), clone(), grep(), any(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(Groov

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

```
${__groovy(new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss').parse('2019.07.12 08:00:00').getTime(),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)